# SalesForce-Marketing Cloud Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have connected Service Cloud from Marketing Cloud>email studio>admin>SalesForce Integration, I can see the service cloud objects in the synced data and can use them.
I haven't installed the managed package "Marketing Cloud V5" in service cloud.
My question is if I do not install the managed package in service cloud, what will I miss?
Sending emails from service cloud is not a requirement.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: follow this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_install_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks,I am aware of the steps to install the marketing cloud connect package in service cloud, my question was more of if I do not do it and only complete the mc part of the integration what happens as I can see the entities in marketing cloud.